# How can I take lists text in middle?

Tags: html, css, text, text-styling

==Here I need to take my text at the middle of the balls.

this is my output, but i need these text in middle
[image]

```css
.items {
 padding-top: 50px;
 
}
.items ul {
 list-style: none;
}
.items ul li {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 200px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 150px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <ul class="items">
    <li>Printed-T-Shirts</li>
    <li>Get Your Print</li>
    <li>Choose A Design</li>
    <li>Full-T-Shirts</li>
    <li>1-Color-Designs</li>
    <li>MultiColor Designs</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain this question? What do you mean by _Here I need to take my text at the middle of the balls._? Everything is already in middle.

Comment: "Here I need to take my text at the middle of the balls". Ouch..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.items {
 padding-top: 50px;
 
}
.items ul {
 list-style: none;
}
.items ul li {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #ccc;
 border-radius: 200px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 150px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.items ul li p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
   <ul class="items">
    <li><p>Printed-T-Shirts</p></li>
    <li><p>Get Your Print</p></li>
    <li><p>Choose A Design</p></li>
    <li><p>Full-T-Shirts</p></li>
    <li><p>1-Color-Designs</p></li>
    <li><p>MultiColor Designs</p></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height: 200px;` to your `.items ul li`
This gives the li the same **line-heigh**t as its height.

Or if you know that the "balls" contain always the same texts you can fix it with this (add it to `.items ul li`):

```
padding: 89px 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

If the text length is different sometimes and/or dynamic, you should add a `<span>` arround your text and give it `position: absolute;` (dont forget to give the parent, the `li`,  `position: relative;`). Then you can position the span in the center of the balls with top, left, and the translateX and -Y property.
[See for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX)

Comment: @TAHMIDHASANNAFIS no problem. mark the answer which helped you the most as solution, so other people see the solution for the problem